Parallel vector field along a geodesic is a Jacobi field?
Let $M$ be a manifold with a linear connection $\nabla.$ A vector field $V$ along a curve $\gamma$ is said to be parallel along $\gamma$ with respect to $\nabla$ if $D_tV =0$.
Let $\gamma : I \to M$ be a geodesic and $t_0 \in I$. Fix a vector $V_0 \in T_{\gamma(t_0)}M$ such that $V_0$ is orthogonal to $\dot{\gamma}(t_0)$. Then by the Parallel Translation ( John Lee's Introduction to Riemannian manifolds, Theorem 4.32. ), there exists a unique parallel vector field $V$ along $\gamma$ such that $V(t_0) =V_0$.
Note next theorem ( John Lee's book Theorem 10.1 ) :

Theorem 10.1. ( The Jacobi Equation ). Let $\gamma$ be a geodesic and $V$ a vector field along $\gamma$. If $V$ is the variation field of a variation through geodesics, then $V$ satisfies the following equation, called the Jacobi equation :
$$ D_t^2V + R(V, \dot{\gamma})\dot{\gamma} = 0. \tag{10.2}$$

A smooth vector feild along a geodesic that satisfies the Jacobi equation is called a Jacobi field.
Here, 'variation through geodesics' is defined as follows :
Suppose that $I, K \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ are intervals, $\gamma : I \to M$ is a geodesic, and $\Gamma : K \times I \to M$ is a variation of $\gamma$ ( as defined in the John Lee's book Chapter 6 ). We say that $\Gamma$ is a variation through geodesics if each of the main curves $\Gamma_s(t)=\Gamma(s,t)$ is also geodesic.
Q. Then my question is, the above parallel vector field $V$ is a jacobi field? It suffices to show that $V$ is the variation field of a variation through geodesics.
I found next Lemma in the John Lee's book :

Lemma 6.1. If $\gamma$ is an admissible curve and $V$ is a piecewise smooth vector field along $\gamma$, then $V$ is the variation field of some variation of $\gamma$. If $V$ is proper, the variation cna be taken to be proper as well.

This lemma only gaurantees that the above $V$ is the variation field of some variation of $\gamma$, not the variation field of 'a variation through geodesics'. For the case that $V$ is a
'parallel' vector field along $\gamma$, such condition is satisfied?
This question originates from Existence of a parallel orthonormal frame $(E_1, \dots , E_n)$ along $\gamma$ such that $E_n = \dot{\gamma}$. In the question I answered myself and not convince that each $E_1, E_2 ,\dots, E_{n-1}$ are normal along $\gamma$ ( In my argument of the answer in my linked question, for $E_1, E_2, \dots, E_{n-1}$ to become normal, they need to be Jacobi fields. )
EDIT :  Uhm.. I think that our above question is not true in general. For the original linked question below, I think that $E_1 , \dots E_{n-1}$ are normal along $\gamma$ since $(E_1, \dots , E_{n-1} , E_n = \dot{\gamma} )$ forms an orthonormal frame. Anyway, can we construct counter-example?
Can anyone help?

Hint: What is the simplest manifold of nonzero curvature that you know? Do you know what geodesics look like on this manifold? Can you construct a parallel field along a geodesic $\gamma$ which is not a multiple of $\gamma'$?

@Moishe Kohan : I am considering sphere wtih great circle. Perhaps, Jacobi field along great circle is tangential?

That's the one you do not want to use. Try to find one which is orthogonal to the geodesic.

O.K. Let $\gamma : I=[a,b]  \to \mathbb{S}^{2}$ be a great circle. Choose a vector $v \in T_{\gamma(a)}\mathbb{S}^{2}$ which is orthogonal to $\dot{\gamma}(a)$. Then there exists a unique parallel vector field $V$ along $\gamma$ such that $V(a) = v$. Since every parallel transport map along $\gamma$ is  a linear isometry, $V$ is orthogonal to $\gamma$. (C.f. John Lee's Introduction to Riemannian manifold, Proposition 5.5. -(f), (g) . ) If $V$ is a Jacobi field and Jacobi field along great circle is tangential as I commented, then it contradics to that $V$ is orthogonal to the $\gamma$.

Am I following your intention well? Or, should I construct $V$ more concretely?

I guess, you just do not know how to construct Jacobi fields. I cannot help you then.

This is false, and here is a sketch of a counterexample.
Consider the two sphere $S^2 = \{(x,y,z) \in \Bbb R^3 \mid x^2+y^2+z^2= 1\}$ and the parametrized great circle $\gamma(t) = (\cos t, \sin t, 0)$, which is a geodesic.
Consider the vector field $V$ along $\gamma$ given by $V(t) = (0,0,1)$.
Then one easily checks that:

$V$ is tangent to $S^2$ along $\gamma$.
$V$ has unit norm.
$V(t)$ is orthogonal to $\gamma'(t)$ for all $t$.

Since the sphere has constant sectional curvature $1$, it follows that $R(V,\gamma')\gamma' = V$.
To conclude, I let you check as an exercise that $V$ is parallel along $\gamma$, so that $D_t(D_tV) = 0$, and thus
$$D_t(D_tV) + R(V,\gamma')\gamma' = V \neq 0.$$

Elementary question : Why $R(V, \gamma')\gamma' = V$? We have $1 = \operatorname{Rm}(V , \gamma' , \gamma' , V ) :=  \left\langle  R ( V,\gamma')\gamma' , V \right\rangle  $ by John Lee's book Proposition 8.29 .

O.K. I think that at least $R(V, \gamma')\gamma'$ is a scalar multiple of $V$  so that it is not zero ( C.f. Proof of the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality ; Linear Algebra done right, p.172 ) . And this fact is sufficient to show the last nonequality in your answer.

Uhm. O.K. we can furthermore show that the scalar multiplied to $V$ is $1$. So $R( V, \gamma')\gamma' = V$ :)
